# Apiary: Export API as JSON, to generate client code

Tags: apiblueprint, apiary.io, apiary

We all know that apiary rocks (or not.. I think it does), and I was wondering what would it take to take it a step further allow users to export a JSON description of the API? (So developers can script client code generation)

This should help:
http://ttezel.github.io/blog/2013/02/23/stop-writing-rest-api-clients/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are two directions you can explore:

- you can use [Alpaca](https://github.com/pksunkara/alpaca) to generate client SDKs. Alpaca accepts API Blueprint as one of it's input formats
- for more flexibility, you can use [Snowcrash](https://github.com/apiaryio/snowcrash) to parse API Blueprint into JSON - and roll your own code generator.

There are more tools around API Blueprint available at http://apiblueprint.org/

Comment: Alpaca doesn't accept API Blueprint yet. I am working on it though.